# Printing dynamic lines in Python with "for line in file"

Tags: python, function, file, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a program where a user can enter a beginning year and an end year, and the program will print out the winners of a book award for all the years in between. Here is what I have so far:

```
ui = input("Enter a beginning year('q' or 'Q' to quit): ")
ui2 = input("Enter an ending year: ")
file = open("bookListFile.txt", "r")



def getBook(user, user2):
    yearsBetween = int(ui2) - int(ui)
    yearCount = 0
    for line in file:
        while user in line and user.isdigit() and yearCount < yearsBetween:
            print(line)
            yearCount += 1



    getBook(ui, ui2)
```

The problem here is when I print the line, it prints the same line over and over. For example, when I enter 1985 as the beginning year and 2000 as the end year, it will print the same line 15 times instead of the years in between.

Can I get some help here? If possible, could you explain how you did it too?

Comment: Please post your file, or a snippet of it, and the program output. :) On the surface, looks like you might have messed up your looping and variable declarations a little, try commenting each line with pseudo code and your expected values for your test case, if you post that back then we will know the difference between erroneous syntax or erroneous expectation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the while loop is getting caught up and from what I see I think this program would be better served by the range function. (for posterity [Python’s range() Function Explained](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/))

```
def get_book(user, user2):
    year_range = range(user, user2)
    #Instead of manually counting up through the numbers a list is automatically 
    #created through range of the numbers. Starting at user, ending at user2 and auto 
    # stepping up by 1.
    for line in file:
        for i in year_range:
            #Instead of using a while loop and a manual count the for loop auto 
            #counts through the range
            if str(i) in line:
                print(line)
```

If you have any other questions or comments please let me know.